# Ms-Access 2007 locating a string in column value with multiple terms

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I want to search for a query string term like apple in column FRUIT of Access database.
`Select * from table_name where FRUIT = "apple"` works fine, when we are looking for single term.
But FRUIT column contains, multiple terms in its value like banana, orange, apple etc (like tags). So above SQL query doesn't works, while searching.
Also, how to make a SQL query when user wants to search for undefined no of terms eg. he may try apple or apple, orange, or grape orange apple etc i.e he may try searching one or more terms together.

Note: I am also reading http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974570.aspx#scripting05_topic2 for solving above problem. But still, I have not figured out, how to use it for getting those recordset, which met with search criteria.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you have a field in your table that can contain multiple values, like...

`banana, orange, apple`

...and you want to be able to search for records that match one (or more) of these "tags". As matzone's answer illustrates, you can do simple substring matching either by using `InStr()` or by using SQL's `LIKE` operator, as in `WHERE Fruit LIKE "*apple*"`.

However, that will also return rows "tagged" as 'pineapple'. To avoid that problem you'd have to include the delimiters...

```
WHERE Fruit LIKE "*, apple, *"
```

...BUT, if you don't have *leading and trailing* delimiters in your field, i.e.,...

`, banana, orange, apple,`

...then you won't be able to find 'banana' in the original example unless you do...

```
WHERE ((Fruit LIKE "*, banana, *") OR (Fruit LIKE "banana, *"))
```

...and you won't be able to find 'banana' at the *end* of the list unless you also do...

```
WHERE ((Fruit LIKE "*, banana, *") OR (Fruit LIKE "banana, *") OR (Fruit LIKE "*, banana"))
```

(Even if you tried using leading and trailing delimiters, Access has a habit of automatically trimming trailing whitespace from fields when they are edited, which could further complicate matters.)

Now throw in the requirement to search for multiple "tags", say, 'banana' OR 'apple', and your WHERE clause becomes

```
WHERE ((Fruit LIKE "*, banana, *") OR (Fruit LIKE "banana, *") OR (Fruit LIKE "*, banana"))
    OR ((Fruit LIKE "*, apple, *") OR (Fruit LIKE "apple, *") OR (Fruit LIKE "*, apple"))
```

Sure, you can build that type of query in VBA code, but it will start to get unweildy (and rather inefficient) pretty quickly.

**My recommendation:** Fix your data structure. Break out your "tags" into a separate child table like this...

```
parentID  fruitTag
--------  --------
       1  banana
       1  orange
       1  apple
```

...and then you can use *equals* conditions to search for tags (via a query with an INNER JOIN between the two tables). You can also index the [fruitTag] field for faster searching. (The `InStr()` and `LIKE "*tag*"` approaches cannot take advantage of indexing.)

Comment: Thanks, for illustrative examples. Currently efficiency and speed are not my concerns, since it is trial project of myself. I was storing input values (user may enter two or more fruit names) separated by space characters in array. So can we have a query, which can go through array values and produce recrodset. What I was doing, Looping through array values, producing a recrodset and appending it with another record set of other search term and later on producing final recordset. But this idea seems pretty bad. Any suggestion of doing it, in smart manner.

Comment: @msinfo If you are considering looping through the array and you want to keep the tags in a single field then you *could*: **(1)** use a non-space delimiter that cannot appear in the tag itself (the "pipe" character `|` is a popular choice), **(2)** use *leading* AND *trailing* delimiters (e.g. `|tag1|tag2|`), then **(3)** use the loop to build a multi-part WHERE clause, e.g. `WHERE (Fruit LIKE "*|tag1|*") OR (Fruit LIKE "*|tag2|*")`.

Comment: Hey, thanks I got the idea, with your info. I could now say why my code was clunky and cumbersome. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 1):

Like this ..

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE instr(1,fruit,"apple") > 0
```

Comment: Right, it worked. And now how do I handle multiple input parameters like instead of 'apple' user might search for 'apple grape'. Had it been known parameters, we could have used OR operator, but we need to handle unknown parameters.

Comment: @msinfo You don't have any objections to "pineapple" being returned when you search for "apple", or "grapefruit" being returned when you search for "grape"...?

Comment: @Gord Thompson: Yes! I don't want that. So if user searches for terms like 'apple orange' only those record sets should be produced where FRUIT column have words "apple" (not pineapple) and "orange" in it as values.